# How to eliminate modified letters and dates using Mac and Windows

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have vba for Excel running on Windows 7. The Excel document is stored on Dropbox.
When the document is opened from a Mac and stored my national characters (Swedish Å, Ä, Ö) are changed to other characters such as "_" and other non letter characters.

I also have an ouput printing in Excel cells texts and dates. If the date is "2015-06-03" it comes out like that in Windows but from Mac the year is omitted. It becomes "-06-03".

Can anyone tell me what to do make this work also in Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Although I could not repeat your issue using VBA with the Swedish characters (mine came out fine), I could repeat your issue with the date.  It appears you have uncovered a bug in Excel Mac 2011 VBA!

I can confirm that this bug does not exist in Excel Mac 2016 VBA.